# How to find researches outside of your specialty as a Phd student?

Tags: phd, mathematics, computer-science, collaboration, networking

I am a starting CS Phd student whose research involves high performance computing in the form of PDE simulations. My specialty is thus in numerical methods for solving PDEs and all of the regular high performance computing stuff, parallel, GPU, communication algorithms etc.

I have researched into solving computing some critical parts of our simulations with the help of numerical linear algebra. The more I have read and researched about numerical linear algebra that more I am interested in it, from high performance parts to numerical stability and roundoff-error analysis which is more in the area of numerical analysis.

Given that the focus of my Phd will be on PDE simulations and I don't think anyone at my department researches numerical linear algebra, outside of some really math heavy finite element stuff. From my point of view having broader research experience would be nice and getting experience in a field that I find exciting would of course by useful.

However is it realistic to get someone to collaborate with outside of my department as I am a PhD student without a formal background in numerical analysis for example? And how should I start finding possible collaborators?

Comment: Have you discussed with your advisor? They may well have contacts that are relevant. And don't discount the 'math heavy finite element stuff' people as being useful contacts.